# Is there a resource where I can see the logical form of an English sentence?

Tags: phrase-structure

There are plenty of resources to generate trees from natural language, but none to generate logical forms. Or maybe you know of some great resources to those ends?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "logical form". A first-order formula? Or a higher-order expression (as in LFG)? Should it contain all logical connectives and quantifiers or rather be flat and scope-free? Any LFG parser will provide a (simplistic) LF.